# Border around collapsed table row when expanding

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a table with multiple rows and I am trying to make the border of a row expand over other rows when it is not collapsed. See the image below. I am using bootstrap 5 and JQuery.
I have made an image to visualize better what I mean:
[image]

You can see how the border wraps the individual makers in "T-Shirts".
My code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr:not(.header)').hide();
  
    $('tr.header').click(function() {
      $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
        return value == '^' ? 'v' : '^'
      });
      
      $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100, function() {});
    });
  });
```

```css
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  transform: scale(1.20);
  padding: 10px;
}

.text-xs {
  font-size: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

table tr {
  border-spacing: 0 18px;
}

tr:not(.thead){
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr:not(.header){
 transform: scale(0.90);
}

tr:not(.addButton):not(.header) {
  outline: 1px solid #0F6DFD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <table class="table table-md table-borderless" id="table" style="width: 65%; color: #117AFF;">
          <thead>
            <tr class="header .thead">
              <th width="10%">NUMBER</th>
              <th>ITEM</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th width="20%">INFO</th>
              <th width="10%">INCLUDE</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr class="header mt-3 shadow-sm">
            <th>042</th>
            <th colspan="3">T-Shirt</th>
            <th><span class="">v</span></th>
            <th><input class="form-check-input mx-auto d-block" type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="pt-3 shadow-sm">
            <td class="align-middle col-1"><img src="img/bars-staggered-solid.svg" class="img-fluid w-25 mx-auto d-block"></td>
            <td class="align-middle col-1"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
            <td class="align-middle col-8">Nike</td>
            <td class="align-middle col-6" colspan="2">   
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
              <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
              <div class="text-xs">2 comments</div>
            </div>
          </td>
            <td class="align-middle"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="pt-3 shadow-sm">
            <td class="align-middle col-1"><img src="img/bars-staggered-solid.svg" class="img-fluid w-25 mx-auto d-block"></td>
            <td class="align-middle col-1"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
            <td class="align-middle col-8">Adidas</td>
            <td class="align-middle col-4" colspan="2">   
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
              <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
              <div class="text-xs">2 comments</div>
            </div>
          </td>
            <td class="align-middle"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="addButton">
            <td colspan="6" width="100%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success fw-light" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Add new</a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: It is not obvious what you want to border. What is the expected output of the actual code?

Comment: The code is my starting point. I want to have one continuous border around "042 - T-shirts" like in the image. That means one border around row with class "header" and the rows before the next row with class "header"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

I started by making the table HTML valid

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').hide();

  $('tr.header').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
      return value == '^' ? 'v' : '^'
    });

    $('tbody').slideToggle(100, function() {});
  });
});
```

```css
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
  transform: scale(1.20);
  padding: 10px;
}

.text-xs {
  font-size: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

table tr {
  border-spacing: 0 18px;
}

tbody {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid #0F6DFD;
}

tr:not(.thead) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

tr:not(.header) {
  transform: scale(0.90);
}

tr:not(.addButton):not(.header) {
  outline: 1px solid #0F6DFD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-md table-borderless" id="table" style="width: 65%; color: #117AFF;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header .thead">
      <th width="10%">NUMBER</th>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th width="20%">INFO</th>
      <th width="10%">INCLUDE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="pt-3 shadow-sm">
    <tr class="header mt-3 shadow-sm">
      <th>042</th>
      <th colspan="3">T-Shirt</th>
      <th><span class="">v</span></th>
      <th><input class="form-check-input mx-auto d-block" type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pt-3 shadow-sm">
      <td class="align-middle col-1"><img src="img/bars-staggered-solid.svg" class="img-fluid w-25 mx-auto d-block"></td>
      <td class="align-middle col-1"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
      <td class="align-middle col-8">Nike</td>
      <td class="align-middle col-6" colspan="2">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
          <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
          <div class="text-xs">2 comments</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pt-3 shadow-sm">
      <td class="align-middle col-1"><img src="img/bars-staggered-solid.svg" class="img-fluid w-25 mx-auto d-block"></td>
      <td class="align-middle col-1"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"></td>
      <td class="align-middle col-8">Adidas</td>
      <td class="align-middle col-4" colspan="2">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
          <div class="text-xs">0 times, 0 times by Client</div>
          <div class="text-xs">2 comments</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="addButton">
      <td colspan="6" width="100%"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success fw-light" role="button" aria-disabled="true">Add new</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: More like a border around the "042" column that expands and is around the "Nike" and "Adidas" rows as well when opened. If you see my image: "023" is what it should look like when closed and "042" when opened.

Comment: Ok, I have given you some hints. I suggest you do not use tables but grid or flex and wrap the items in divs

Comment: Ok, I agree, maybe divs are better.